# Как запустить cython файл напрямую?

Tags: python, многопоточность, cython

Есть файл .pyx, в нем используется библиотека multiprocessing, а конкретно класс Process, и из-за него нужно чтобы файл запускался напрямую а не импортировался другим пайтон файлом, так как используется конструкция

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Без которой ничего не работает, ну и плюс так будет намного проще, так как мне по сути нужно просто запустить этот файл не импортируя его из других питоновских файлов, можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Вы оформите код запуска Process в функции или классе, и вызывайте это в блоке if __name__... Всё! То есть в контексте if __name__...

Comment: Для начала покажите ваши оба скрипта, что бы было понятно о чём речь, иначе вы не дождетесь ответа.